# unrecognized inateck hdd enclosure with linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, hard-disk, kernel-modules, bios

I have put in a Hitachi 2.5 inch hdd inside a [Inateck hdd enclosure](http://www.inateck.com/download/inateck-2-5-inch-usb-3-0-hard-drive-disk-hdd-external-enclosure-case-with-usb-3-0-cable/). I have connected the enclosure to a Toshiba R630-156 using a usb2 cable on a usb3 enclosure port. I can hear and feel the hard drive is powered but I cannot see any messages in dmesg. i cannot see any related output in lsusb. I have enabled usb_storage kernel module but it does not seem to make any difference. I am not experienced with trouble shooting hardware issues so please refer to some documentation if you are using very specific terms in your explanation. please ask if you need anymore debug information. thanks.

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17
DISTRIB_CODENAME=qiana
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17 Qiana"

$ uname -a
Linux rag-tos-laptop 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsmod | grep usb
usb_storage            62209  0 
btusb                  32412  0 
bluetooth             395423  12 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
usbhid                 52616  0 
hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0930:0214 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:58f5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

BIOS Information
        Vendor: TOSHIBA
        Version: Version 1.90  
        Release Date: 02/24/2011
        ROM Size: 2048 kB
        Characteristics:
                ISA is supported
                PCI is supported
                PNP is supported
                BIOS is upgradeable
                BIOS shadowing is allowed
                VLB is supported
                Boot from CD is supported
                Selectable boot is supported
                EDD is supported
                Japanese floppy for Toshiba 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
                3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
                8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
                Serial services are supported (int 14h)
                Printer services are supported (int 17h)
                ACPI is supported
                USB legacy is supported
                BIOS boot specification is supported
                Function key-initiated network boot is supported
                Targeted content distribution is supported
        BIOS Revision: 1.90
        Firmware Revision: 1.40
```

Comment: The enclosure is usb3. What makes you think it would work with a usb2 port? usb3 can use much more power, aside from all other protocol differences.

Comment: i have a patriot usb3 pen drive; that is detected and works when connected to a usb2 port on my laptop; i thought originally if you use a usb3 device in a usb2 port it only affects the throughput but not the function itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, I just realized that when using a usb3 cable and connecting to a usb2 port on the laptop, the device is found and all the partitions are automatically mounted.

The problem I had earlier could be from the usb2 cable which could carry only less power than a usb3 device required.

```
/dev/sdb5 on /media/r/3c45f792-1630-4866-8a33-1534c115f285 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb6 on /media/r/ce13cd6c-57bd-4beb-b489-10e2aa2a7876 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/r/SYSTEM type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/mapper/vgroup1-mymedia on /media/r/dc1afac9-27cc-4f76-95a6-91f0ac0060ef type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/mapper/vgroup1-virtualization on /media/r/c71ff7a8-bfee-48e1-9ab1-25e6a8ecd829 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)

kernel: [13587.330014]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4 < sdb5 sdb6 sdb7 sdb8 >
kernel: [13587.333642] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
kernel: [13589.035776] EXT4-fs (sdb5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
kernel: [13589.038729] EXT4-fs (sdb6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
kernel: [13592.827240] bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
kernel: [13595.524660] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
kernel: [13598.882851] EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```